# Translating a MySQL query into Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to turn the following query into Laravel Eloquent.

```sql
select * from tool where id not in (select tool_id from product_tool where product_id = 1)
```

So far, I have tried the following.

```php
$cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
if (empty($cari)) {
    abort(404);
}

$productTool = ProductTool::where('product_id', $cari->id)->get();
foreach ($productTool as $data) {
    $tools = Tool::whereNotIn('id', [$data->tool_id])->get();
}
```

The problem is when I dd() the $tools, it just returns one array. It needs to return two arrays, because in the product_tool table (which is many to many from products and tools table) product_id 1 have id [1,2] of tool_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please try this is the pure laravel eloquent.

```
$cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();

if (empty($cari)) {
    abort(404);
}

$tools = Tool::whereNotIn('id', ProductTool::where('product_id', $cari->id)
->pluck('tool_id')->toArray())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    use get() instead of first()

 $cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->get();

    when you use first() function it will return only one array.
    use get()
```

Comment: i use first() because, i don't know to tell you but, it is like findOrFail() when i want show something. so it just like find an id but i use slug. sorry if you are confused :'

Answer (score 0):

your code missing $tools[] , by put [] in front of your variable, it won't override the first key

```
 $tools = [];
 $cari = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
 if (empty($cari)) {
    abort(404);
}
$productTool = ProductTool::where('product_id', $cari->id)->get();        
foreach ($productTool as $data) {
    $tools[] = Tool::whereNotIn('id', [$data->tool_id])->get();
}
```

therefore $tools now returning 2 arrays

Comment: the $tools return 2 arrays now. but the problem now is on view, i tried to foreach $tools. but it give me errors ''Property [tool_name] does not exist on this collection instance.'' the tool_name is field on the table tools.